# A traveller of realms

Tags: riddle

> He is mortal to one,
>   He is divine to another,
>   He is a slave to time,
>   And yet he is beyond its grasps,
>   Incomprehensible to one,
>   Yet simple to another.

Who is he?

Hint:
He exists in real life.

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, but it sounds pretty good. Is this your own riddle?

Comment: Yep :P. I've just edited it so it's actually on different lines.

Comment: Nice work, and I still have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

I think he is

> Thor

He is mortal to one,

> mortal for his own realm

He is divine to another,

> but divine for people on earth

He is a slave to time,

> He cannot escape time as he will grow old as his father

And yet he is beyond its grasps,

> he can travel through his gate(a warm hole) avoiding the huge time (and not very sure though, time in asgard is relatively very slow as compared to earth)

Incomprehensible to one,

> to humans

Yet simple to another

> i.e., to his own people

Comment: Wow, you are really, really close. The time aspect is still a bit off, but the first and last two are matching in terms of what I was trying to get at. Keep it up ;)

Comment: @MinusReputation: I think An Astronaut can be the best candidate for this.

Comment: It doesn't fit the 'immortality' bit.

Answer (score 3):

Is he:

> The Doctor from Doctor Who

He is mortal to one,

> He "dies" every so often...

He is divine to another,

> ... only to be reincarnated as the new Doctor Who

He is a slave to time,

> He moves through time...

And yet he is beyond its grasps,

> ...but he's a time lord.

Incomprehensible to one,

> Play on the name Doctor *Who*...

Yet simple to another.

> ... but he's simply a good guy trying his best to right the situation.

Comment: Just a pet peeve of mine, but Doctor Who is just the show, the character is  just the Doctor

Comment: @ChillFruit es edited answer accordingly

Comment: Hmm... it's a close answer, but the 'slave to time' line doesn't quite apply. Nice guess though.

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to guess this

> But I think the expected answer is Jesus Christ. The clues refer to Jesus' dual nature as God and man and this is either simple or incomprehensible depending on whether or not you believe. If this is the answer, though , I'm not sure it qualifies as a riddle.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> The Dalai Lama?

He is mortal to one,
He is divine to another,

> Depending on your belief he's either just some guy or a reincarnated religious figure.

He is a slave to time,
And yet he is beyond its grasps,

> I think the reincarnation aspect also covers this part.

Incomprehensible to one,
Yet simple to another.

> In terms of simple/incomprehensible I think it also comes down to whether you believe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Jesus

He is mortal to one,

> He was mortal in his form on Earth (got crucified)

He is divine to another,

> In heaven he is divine.

He is a slave to time,

> He was only on Earth for a brief period

And yet he is beyond its grasps,

> Heaven is a place without time.

Incomprehensible to one,

> His actions were like magic to those who didn't believe

Yet simple to another.

> Yet to others they were simply acts of God.

Hint:

> Whilst I'm not actually religious, I believe there was actually a bloke called Jesus who spread the word of God at the time.